# unable to use redux in app made using create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux, create-react-app

When I create a new app using `create-react-app`, redux and react-redux folders are not in the node_modules. I have installed `redux` and `react-redux` with npm.

Still, I am not able to use redux into my react project.

Please help me, thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

Redux and React-redux are not part of a newly created create-react-app application. If you want to have it, you have to install it by yourself:

```
create-react-app my-app
cd my-app/
npm install --save redux react-redux
```

Answer (score 0):

The create react app script will only do the bare bones setup. For any additional modules you want to install you'll need to do so manually.

From the command lines it's pretty simple. For example:

`npm i --save redux`

- The 'i' stands for install
- The --save will add it to your package.json dependencies. For some dependencies you may want to do --save-dev instead. These won't be included in a production build (e.g. Dev moudules).
- You can also replace the 'i' with 'uninstall' (optionally with the save flags) to remove a dependency you no longer want.

Periodically you'll also want to run the following to update your projects dependencies:

```
npm update
```